# A question about articles- "the source of the ambiguity" Vs "source of the ambiguity"

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

Suppose that we have a piece of writing which is ambiguous in some parts. Now, I want to give my reason about the issue.

I want to use the noun **source**. (I know I can say that in many ways)

I would say:

> I guess the lack of detailed context is **the** source of the ambiguity.

Should I use the definite article before *source*? I am saying that because I am not talk about a specific source.So, if I omit the article, then how different will the sentence be?

Would it be grammatical? If so, what will change?

Comment: *source* is a countable noun, so you have to use an article just like you would for any other countable noun.

Comment: @stangdon OK thanks, but couldn't it be an abstract noun in that context?

Comment: It seems be a common misconception that we don't use articles for abstract nouns, but we use articles for abstract nouns just like we use them for anything else: "I had **a** thought" or "I follow **the** religion of my ancestors."  What we don't use articles for is only noncount nouns or general concepts, whether they're abstract or not: "I like pudding" or "I study philosophy".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These would all be correct:

a) I guess the lack of detailed context **is the source** of the ambiguity.

b) I guess the lack of detailed context **is one source** of the ambiguity.

c) I guess the lack of detailed context **is a source** of the ambiguity.

This would be incorrect:

d) I guess the lack of detailed context **is source** of the ambiguity.

(But to me, choice a) sounds better than b) or c) because it sounds strange to use "the" ambiguity if there is more than one source of ambiguity. I would say that there is more than one source **of ambiguity**, not more than one source **of the ambiguity**. That's a more subjective question, almost a question of style.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. articles are really challenging. I thought that "source", here, can be an abstract noun, so I can omit the article without making it wrong.